Please help to adjust the landscape-mode table
The last two columns are overflowing the window boundary.
I have used \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle} which I am attaching also. The MWE that I tried is as follows
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Overview of Assistive Devices for Obstacle Detection}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{1cm}p{3.2cm}p{3.2cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{3cm}p{1.4cm}p{1.2cm}p{3cm}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Sensor Type} & \textbf{Device Name} & \textbf{Detection Method} & \textbf{Processing} & \textbf{Key Features} & \textbf{Accuracy (\%)} & \textbf{Cost} & \textbf{Limitations} \\
\midrule

[1] & 2.45 GHz CW Radar & Radar-Based Fall Detector & Analog Decision Tree & On-device (Analog IC) & Power Burst Curve, Effective Acceleration & 98.76 & High & Sensitive to environment, complex circuit design, scalability issues \\

[2] & Ultrasound, Fisheye & Smart Shoe System & Obstacle Detection & On-device & Pothole \& Staircase Alerts & 95.06 & Moderate & Requires precise calibration \\

[3] & Ultrasound, Infrared & Shoe System & Obstacle Detection & On-device & Detects if Shoe is Worn & 97.00 & Moderate & Limited range detection \\

[4] & Ultrasound & Blind Shoe & Wet Surface Detection & On-device & Buzzer \& Audio Alerts & 97.33 & Low & Limited obstacle detection \\

[5] & Infrared & Obstacle Detection Shoe & Direction Control & On-device & Buzzer Alert, Directional & 95.33 & Low & Short detection range \\

[6] & Camera, Ultrasound & COMPASS Smart Shoe & Image \& Text Detection & Remote & Beeper Notifications & 98.76 & High & Complex hardware setup \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}

The elsarticle class file

I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting, as sidewaystable has a very specific meaning in a LaTeX context.

A tabularx environment must have at least ond X-type column. In addition, many of the p-type columns are currently too wide, preventing the table from fitting inside the text block. I'd also reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. Finally, getting rid of the bold-facing in the header row also saves quite a bit of space.

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % optional
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e, tabularx, pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % ditto

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Overview of Assistive Devices for Obstacle Detection}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
   l
   P{2.25cm}
   P{2.25cm}
   P{2.75cm}
   P{2cm}
   P{2.25cm}
   P{1.3cm}
   P{1cm}
   L @{}}
\toprule
Ref & Sensor type & Device name & Detection method & Processing & Key features & Acc. (\%) & Cost & Limitations \\
\midrule

[1] & 2.45 GHz CW Radar & Radar-Based Fall Detector & Analog Decision Tree & On-device (Analog IC) & Power Burst Curve, Effective Acceleration & 98.76 & High & Sensitive to environment, complex circuit design, scalability issues \\

[2] & Ultrasound, Fisheye & Smart Shoe System & Obstacle Detection & On-device & Pothole \& Staircase Alerts & 95.06 & Moderate & Requires precise calibration \\

[3] & Ultrasound, Infrared & Shoe System & Obstacle Detection & On-device & Detects if shoe is worn & 97.00 & Moderate & Limited range detection \\

[4] & Ultrasound & Blind Shoe & Wet Surface Detection & On-device & Buzzer \& Audio Alerts & 97.33 & Low & Limited obstacle detection \\

[5] & Infrared & Obstacle Detection Shoe & Direction Control & On-device & Buzzer Alert, Directional & 95.33 & Low & Short detection range \\

[6] & Camera, Ultrasound & COMPASS Smart Shoe & Image \& Text Detection & Remote & Beeper Notifications & 98.76 & High & Complex hardware setup \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


An alternative, as complement to nice @Mico answer (+1) with use of the tblr of tabularray package, \small font size (for better text fitting in cells) and automatic numbering of rows (here I'm not sure, if maybe in the first column actually are commands \cite{...}; if yes, than the row in table preamble marked by % <--- should be deleted and in cells inserted \cite commands):
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % optional
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Overview of Assistive Devices for Obstacle Detection}
\begin{tblr}{colsep = 2pt,
             colspec= {@{}  l 
                            X X[1.1] X[1.1] X X
                            X[0.5,c,si={table-format=2.2}]
                            X[0.5] X[1.8]
                       @{} },
             cells  = {font=\small, cmd=\RaggedRight},
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=[\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1]}, % <---
             row{1} = {c, m, guard}
             }
    \toprule
Ref & Sensor type 
        & Device name
            & Detection method 
                & Processing 
                    & {Key\\ features} 
                        & {Acc.\\ (\%)}
                            & Cost 
                                & Limitations \\
    \midrule
    & \qty{2.45}{\giga\hertz} CW Radar 
        & Radar-Based Fall Detector 
            & Analog Decision Tree 
                & On-device (Analog IC) 
                    & Power Burst Curve, Effective Acceleration
                        & 98.76 
                            & High
                                & Sensitive to environment, complex circuit design, scalability issues 
                                \\
    & Ultrasound, Fisheye 
        & Smart Shoe System 
            & Obstacle Detection 
                & On-device 
                    & Pothole \& Staircase Alerts 
                        & 95.06 
                            & Mode\-rate 
                                & Requires precise calibration      \\
    & Ultrasound, Infrared 
        & Shoe System 
            & Obstacle Detection 
                & On-device 
                    & Detects if shoe is worn 
                        & 97.00 
                            & Mode\-rate 
                                & Limited range detection           \\
    & Ultrasound 
        & Blind Shoe
            & Wet Surface Detection
                & On-device
                    & Buzzer \& Audio Alerts
                        & 97.33
                            & Low
                                & Limited obstacle detection        \\
    & Infrared 
        & Obstacle Detection Shoe & Direction Control & On-device & Buzzer Alert, Directional & 95.33 & Low & Short detection range \\
    & Camera, Ultrasound 
        & COMPASS Smart Shoe 
            & Image \& Text Detection 
                & Remote 
                    & Beeper Notifications 
                        & 98.76 
                            & High 
                                & Complex hardware setup            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


